# Ensuring the same vertical space after a knitrout environment

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I am using knitr to embed R code and output into a textbook I am writing. In my textbook, I first write the R code with a dark gray background and then run the R code in the next chunk with a lighter background. I basically do the following:

```
<<eval = F, background = "gray90">>=
2+2
@

\vspace{-.6cm}
<<eval = T, echo = F, background = "gray95">>=
2+2
@
```

I use `\vspace{-.6cm}` to make the spacing between the two chunks smaller.

However, this doesn't ensure the same vertical spacing between chunks because it seems to be affected by the amount of text, images, etc that are on the current page.

The screenshot below shows this problem.

[image]

The first two chunks were created by:

```
<<eval = F, background = "gray90">>=
cor(latent_est)
@

\vspace{-.6cm}
<<eval = T, echo = F, background = "gray95">>=
cor(latent_est)
@
```

and the last two chunks were:

```
<<eval = F, background = "gray90">>=
rmsd(latent_est$MLE, latent_est$MAP)
rmsd(latent_est$MLE, latent_est$EAP)
rmsd(latent_est$MAP, latent_est$EAP)
@

\vspace{-.6cm}
<<eval = T, echo = F, background = "gray95">>=
rmsd(latent_est$MLE, latent_est$MAP)
rmsd(latent_est$MLE, latent_est$EAP)
rmsd(latent_est$MAP, latent_est$EAP)
@
```

I know this is probably not the best way to insert vertical space but I'm wondering if there's a way to consistently add the same vertical space after a chunk?

Below is an example that reproduces this. Note the `\section{}` messes up the vertical spacing this time. How can I always get the spacing the same after a chunk?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

% Misbehaving chunks!
\begin{equation}
RMSD=\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{N}(\hat{\theta}_{1j}-\hat{\theta}_{2j})^2}{N}},
\end{equation}
\blindtext

<<eval = F, background = "gray90">>=
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)
summary(lm.D9)
@

\vspace{-.6cm}
<<eval = T, echo = F, background = "gray95">>=
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)
summary(lm.D9)
@

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text

\section{Model Diagnostics}

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text

\newpage


% Correct chunks!
\begin{equation}
RMSD=\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{N}(\hat{\theta}_{1j}-\hat{\theta}_{2j})^2}{N}},
\end{equation}
\blindtext

<<eval = F, background = "gray90">>=
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)
summary(lm.D9)
@

\vspace{-.6cm}
<<eval = T, echo = F, background = "gray95">>=
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)
summary(lm.D9)
@

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `\usepackage{parskip}` in your preamble.

[image: Misbehaving chunk]

[image: Correct chunk]